# how to use angular 2 file uploaf in ES5?

Tags: angular

I try to use angular 2 file upload, yet it's only explained for TypeScript, and I'm using ES5

what should I do?

I use this library:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

I know Angular 2 can be written in ES5 and I have already written applications in ES5 using Angular 2 and Material 2

Comment: If you have already written applications in ES5 what is the problem with it?

Comment: I can't find its module or directives etc. in global space like ng.core or ng.common, and also I don't know where to add things in the module definition.

Comment: I will try to help. Seems plunker doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

To use `ng2-file-upload` package with es5 you can take umd bundle

https://unpkg.com/ng2-file-upload@1.2.0/bundles/ng2-file-upload.umd.js

If you open it you can notice

```
root["ng2-file-upload.umd"] = factory(root["@angular/core"], root["@angular/common"]);
```

So before loading this script without any loaders you have to do something like this:

```
window["@angular/core"] = ng.core;
window["@angular/common"] = ng.common;
```

then you can get reference to `FileUploadModule` module and other classes via:

```
var FileUploadModule = window['ng2-file-upload.umd'].FileUploadModule;
```

**[JsFiddle Example Angular2 v4.0.1 es5 nf2-file-upload](https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/u32e819a/)**

Comment: such a nice explanation